# Different np.std behaviours in pd.apply

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Numpy std function seems to be giving different ddof values in pd.apply depending on whether or not the apply argument is an iterable.

In other words, the line

> pd.DataFrame([0, 1]).apply(np.std)

Produces different value from

> pd.DataFrame([0, 1]).apply([np.std])

The first one is the correct for numpy with ddof=0 while the second one is the Pandas default with ddof=1.

Why is that the case? What changes from a single argument to a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is because [under the covers](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/apply.py#L140) of `pd.DataFrame.apply` it uses `pd.DataFrame.aggregate` if you pass a list-like object, and in `aggregate` it's replaced with `Series.std()`, which has the default `ddof=1` value. Hence the result:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame([0, 1]).apply([np.std])
               0
std     0.707107
```

In the other case when you pass `np.std` as a regular function, then it doesn't go through any replacement, and `np.std` has `ddof=0` as default, so this becomes:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame([0, 1]).apply(np.std)
0    0.5
dtype: float64
```

This is actually a "wontfix" issue: [see here.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13344) If you want to skip the replacement of numpy functions into pandas functions use it as follows (from the linked github issue):

`.groupby(...).agg(lambda x: np.std(x))`