# Different np.std behaviours in pd.DataFrame.transform

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The default option of the degrees of freedom `ddof` in `np.std` is `ddof=0`.

When using `np.std` within `pd.DataFrame.transform`, this behavior changes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9],
                   "group": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"]})
std = df.groupby("group")["col1"].transform(np.std)
```

The output is

```
0    1.000000
1    1.000000
2    1.000000
3    2.645751
4    2.645751
5    2.645751
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Meanwhile, `np.std([1, 2, 3]) = 0.816496580927726` and `np.std([1, 2, 3], ddof=1) = 1.0`.

It seems like there is a different `std()` or with different options used, when using `pd.DataFrame.transform`.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy fix is to add the `ddof=0` to the `pd.DataFrame.transform` options:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9],
                   "group": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"]})
std = df.groupby("group")["col1"].transform(np.std, ddof=0)  # <- fix
```

The output then is:

```
0    0.816497
1    0.816497
2    0.816497
3    2.160247
4    2.160247
5    2.160247
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

See here for the similar answer for `pd.DataFrame.apply`: [Different np.std behaviours in pd.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557143/different-np-std-behaviours-in-pd-apply) and [Pandas agg function gives different results for numpy std vs nanstd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676250/pandas-agg-function-gives-different-results-for-numpy-std-vs-nanstd)